# Rust enum and match : How does it distinguishes two different enums that takes in two different struct but same contents

Tags: rust, enums, match, solana

I am trying to understand following enum [from this repo](https://github.com/tomoima525/solana-sandbox/blob/main/rust/escrow/program/src/instruction.rs)

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct InitEscrowArgs {
  pub data: EscrowReceive,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct ExchangeArgs {
  pub data: EscrowReceive,
}

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Clone)]
pub enum EscrowInstruction {
  InitEscrow(InitEscrowArgs),

  Exchange(ExchangeArgs),

  CancelEscrow(),
}
```

and it's use of it in this match [from this repo](https://github.com/tomoima525/solana-sandbox/blob/f2e228396ca089163737bc6f171775fe1855fc54/rust/escrow/program/src/processor.rs#L51).

```
  pub fn process(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
  ) -> ProgramResult {
    let instruction = EscrowInstruction::try_from_slice(instruction_data)?;

    match instruction {
      EscrowInstruction::InitEscrow(args) => {
        msg!("Instruction: Init Escrow");
        Self::process_init_escrow(program_id, accounts, args.data.amount)
      }
      EscrowInstruction::Exchange(args) => {
        msg!("Instruction: Exchange Escrow");
        Self::process_exchange(program_id, accounts, args.data.amount)
      }
      EscrowInstruction::CancelEscrow() => {
        msg!("Instruction: Cancel Escrow");
        Self::process_cancel(program_id, accounts)
      }
    }
  }
```

I understand that this try_from_slice method gets some sort of byte array and deserialize it.

I do not understand how it determines which enum value to use.

The enum has 3 choices, InitEscrow / Exchange / CancelEscrow, but what determines the match to know which one it is suppose to select?

Seem to me the InitEscrowArgs and ExchangeArgs both takes in same struct. Both containing data that is EscrowReceive data type.

Comment: include ALL neccesary information IN your question, link of extern ressource are only for additionnal not mandatory context.

Comment: "I do not understand how it determines which enum value to use." enum have variant value, like "0, 1, 2, etc" the compiler job to select an unique value. When you do a pattern matching on an enum value, the compiler add the nessesary code to determine what is the value of the enum, it's a "runtime check" (totally normal) I think you should read the rust book chapter about enumeration

Comment: @Stargateur thank you for pointing out the insight regarding contents of the post. I have updated and made sure the reader does not have to leave the site unless desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `try_from_slice` is part of the [BorshDeserialize](https://docs.rs/borsh/latest/borsh/de/trait.BorshDeserialize.html) trait, which is derived on the enum in question. So, the choice between enum variants is made by the implementation of deserializer.

To see what is really going on, I've built the simplest possible example:

```
use borsh::BorshDeserialize;

#[derive(BorshDeserialize)]
enum Enum {
    Variant1(u8),
    Variant2,
}
```

By using [`cargo expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) and a little manual cleanup, we can get the following equivalent code:

```
impl borsh::de::BorshDeserialize for Enum {
    fn deserialize(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> Result<Self, std::io::Error> {
        let variant_idx: u8 = borsh::BorshDeserialize::deserialize(buf)?;
        let return_value = match variant_idx {
            0u8 => Enum::Variant1(borsh::BorshDeserialize::deserialize(buf)?),
            1u8 => Enum::Variant2,
            _ => {
                let msg = format!("Unexpected variant index: {}", variant_idx);
                return Err(std::io::Error::new(
                    std::io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput,
                    msg,
                ));
            }
        };
        Ok(return_value)
    }
}
```

Where the inner `deserialize` calls refers to [`impl BorshDeserialize for u8`](https://docs.rs/borsh/latest/src/borsh/de/mod.rs.html#61-104):

```
fn deserialize(buf: &mut &[u8]) -> Result<Self> {
    if buf.is_empty() {
        return Err(Error::new(
            ErrorKind::InvalidInput,
            ERROR_UNEXPECTED_LENGTH_OF_INPUT,
        ));
    }
    let res = buf[0];
    *buf = &buf[1..];
    Ok(res)
}
```

So, it works the following way:

- Deserializer tries to pull one byte from input; if there's none - this is an error.
- This byte is interpreted as an index of enum variant; if it doesn't match to one of variants - this is an error.
- If the variant contains any data, deserializer tries to pull this data from the input; if it fails (according to the inner type's implementation) - this is an error.

Comment: Ohhhhh Ok(res) is returned and hence is stored in variable `instruction`!!! And because the instruction contains the enum identifier, it is able to identify the path to take... Very easy to understand. Thank you so much!!